# passing a noncontiguous array section in Fortran

Tags: fortran, intel, intel-mkl

I am using intel fortran compiler and intel mkl for a performance check. I am passing some array sections to Fortran 77 interface with calls like

```
call dgemm( transa,transb,sz_s,P,P,&
            a, Ts_tilde,&
            sz_s,R_alpha,P,b,tr(:sz_s,:),sz_s)
```

as evident, tr(:sz_s,:) is not contiguous in memory and the Fortran 77 interface is expecting a continuous block and creating a temporary for this.

What I was wondering is that will there be a difference if I create my temporary array explicitly in the code for tr and copy information from that temporary back and forth before and after the operation, or will that be the same as compiler itself creating the temporary from a performance point of view? I guess compiler will always be more efficient.

And of course any more suggestions to eliminate these temporaries are welcome.

One more point, If I use the Fortran 95 interface of the library apparently, with a similar call on a simpler test problem, no warning is issued for the creation of a temporary. Then I read in the manual of mkl that Fortran 95 interface uses assumed shape arrays which explains why temporaries are not created.

However at that point, I can not seem to use some support functions like timing routines.
Namely, intel mkl has some timing support functions but if I use them with the mkl_service routine like below then I get 'This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type' error for dsecnd. Any idea for this problem is also welcome. A simple example for this is given as

```
program dgemm95_test
! some modules for Fortran 95 interface
use mkl_service
use mkl95_precision
use mkl95_blas
!
implicit none
!
double precision, dimension(4,3) :: a
double precision, dimension(6,4) :: b
double precision, dimension(5,5) :: r ! result array
double precision, dimension(3,2) :: dummy_b
!
character(len=1) :: transa
character(len=1) :: transb
!
double precision :: alpha, beta, t1, t2, t
integer :: sz1, sz2

! initialize some variables
alpha = 1.0
beta = 0.0
a = 2.3
b = 4.5
r = 0.0
transa = 'n'
transb = 'n'
dummy_b = 0.0
! Fortran 95 interface
t1 = dsecnd()
call gemm( a, b(4:6,1:3:2), r(2:5,3:4),&
 transa, transb, alpha, beta )
t2 = dsecnd()
!
write(*,*) r
dummy_b  = r(2:4,4:5)
!
end program dgemm95_test
```

Comment: I don't see why you would need a temporary at all, you can just use the `tr` matrix and pass it's leading dimension: `call dgemm(transa,transb,sz_s,P,P,a,Ts_tilde,sz_s,R_alpha,P,b,tr,size(tr,1))`

Comment: @steabert, I am learning Fortran with a fast pace, I learned this today by intel mkl forum as well... but thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 6):

The temporary is absolutely necessary when passing your array section to an assumed size array dummy argument, which the old routines use, because the array section is not contiguous in memory.

You can of course make your own temporary arrays. Whether it will be faster or not depends on many factors. Among others the important thing is whether the temporary is allocated on the stack or on the heap. The Intel Fortran compiler is capable of both, there are compiler switches to control the behavior (`-heap-arrays n`) and it can depend on the array size. Stack allocation is much faster and it is usually the default. Automatic arrays, which you might use for your own temporary are allocated on the stack by default too. Be careful with large arrays on the stack, you can easily overflow it and cause a crash.

I would suggest you to make a performance test and use the simpler variant if it is not too slow. Probably it will be the Fortran 95 interface, but you should measure the times, really.

As for the timing, MKL manual page for `second()`/`dsecnd()` states you must include`mkl_lapack.fi` and doesn't speak about any Fortran95 interface. You could get away declaring it external double precision too, but I would use the include. Or use `system_clock()` as a portable standard Fortran 95.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your comments are inline with what I was thinking. For the second part, intel mkl has some timing support functions but if I use them with the mkl_service routine like above then I get 'This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type' error for dsecnd. I made a similar post on intel forums as well...

Comment: But you didn't post this information to the question! Post anything necessary to solve the problem. Personally I just use `system_clock()` everywhere, it is standard and fully portable.

Comment: I am confused here a bit since under the section on support functions in the pdf document, it instructs to either use {'INCLUDE mkl_service.fi' or 'INCLUDE mkl.fi'} or USE mkl_service, I do not get why it can not find the function

Comment: Maybe the module doesn't include the Timing routines, because they are not needed in Fortran 95. I read the specific manual for `dsecnd()` and it doesn't speak about Fortran 95 interface.

Comment: Vladimir, one more questions regarding the temporary, I will create a temporary array and use it for the operations, I will not allocate and deallocate, I know what I have to copy so they will be fixed sized arrays just to copy these array sections, so only copying to and from will be necessary, I guess this can be a fast solution, I should try out.

Comment: @UmutTabak Try and measure, these days almost nobody has fixed size problems (or simply do not want to recompile every time). If you do, you are lucky.